# Ways to storing data on local desktop app with electronjs

Tags: javascript, database, electron

I want to create an app that takes images and text to store and reads them to show. I will use [ElectronJS](https://www.electronjs.org/) for that, but I'm really new to it. ElectronJS uses HTML, CSS, and JavaScript to make cross-platform desktop apps. I don't plan to use any servers to store data. I'm planning to store data on the PC.

But I don't have ideas for how to store it or in what format to store it. Will storing it in HTML files be okay? Do you have any ideas or suggestions?

I expect ideas or suggests to use for solving my problem.

Comment: Electron allows you to use static assets, they will be packed into the executable when you build your app for distribution https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/distribution-overview#packaging

Comment: Just have your application save text as a `.txt` file and images as `.jpeg`,`.png`,`.gif`, etc. files. Use Javascript to dynamically insert them into the DOM. If you wish to associate groups of text and images together, use can use a JSON file as a way to link any titles and their associated text or image file paths together.